# How to definitively keep SSH sessions open while putting laptop to sleep?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I often have a bunch of SSH sessions open, all of which die after putting my laptop to sleep and waking it, even after only a few minutes. This is not ideal to have to reconnect all of these sessions manually.

A few years ago, there were some servers I would often connect to, and was often still connected to them after a few hours of my laptop being asleep. If I remember correctly, this may have even worked 24 hours or more after putting it to sleep. Sometimes, I would even walk between buildings with my laptop asleep, and it would still be able to transparently reconnect much later (I had a static IP address across a campus network).

What I have already tried:

```
# Client
ServerAliveInterval 240
ServerAliveCountMax 720
TCPKeepAlive no

# Server
ClientAliveInterval 240 
ClientAliveCountMax 720
TCPKeepAlive no
```

I believe I tried disabling the alive interval on both client/server as well.

I am aware of other solutions like `autossh`, and I am already using `ssh-agent` locally and `tmux` on the remote end. I am specifically looking for a way that this can be done natively with OpenSSH. Note that the servers are generally reachable on the same network, so there are no routers to worry about, and my computer's address can be assumed to be static.

So, how can I configure my laptop and any servers to allow me to resume SSH connections after sleep?

Comment: You could use ssh-agent instead.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  `ssh-agent` is for storing private keys; I'm not sure how that relates here.

Comment: It's not for storing for private keys. It's to simplify reconnects.

Comment: When your laptop wakes up does it have the same IP address as when it went to sleep?

Comment: @roaima yes, it is always the same.

Comment: What manages your network interfaces? Unmanaged like Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces` or a process like `NetworkManager`? Is it possible that NM is shutting down the interface when it discovers the OS is about to sleep?

Comment: @roaima NetworkManager, but I believe the same has also worked in the past.

Comment: No idea then, sorry

Comment: I realise that this may have worked in the past but I'm not convinced it was ever supposed to.  Putting a laptop to sleep will mean the laptop no longer acknowledges any TCP packets.  Expecting this to work assumes that nothing will be sent by the server while you're gone.  So if the server tries to send anything it will detect the disconnect.  That said have you tried a tool like wireshark to see what's really being sent by your laptop / server when you put your laptop to sleep?

Comment: @PhilipCouling hmmm I would imagine the TCPKeepAlive option would influence that behavior. A packet capture is a good idea, I'll give it a try.

Comment: If your concern is losing state on the server, you could use `screen` or `tmux` to keep the sessions running when you disconnect.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that is mentioned as something I am already doing.

Comment: I just never put my laptop to sleep. I just sleep the display.

Comment: There may well be a stateful firewall between the server and client, in which case there's nothing you can do other than to set up a tunnel and SSH through that tunnel